# Hyperlink does not react when click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink

What I'm trying to do is to use hyperlink to redirect to local folder. The problem that I facing at the moment is the hyperlink seem to do nothing at all? Here are some of the method that I've tried:

1)

```
  Dim FILEPATH As String = ("file:///D:/try/2019/" & id & "/") 
  HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = FILEPATH
```

2)

```
lblFileLink1.Text = " <a href='D:/HitoSensor_Attachment/2019/" & id & "/'>click</a> to see file"
```

3)

```
  Dim FILEPATH As String = ("D:/try/2019/" & id & "/") 
  HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = FILEPATH
```

I've tried all these three yet the hyperlink react the same which is nothing. Is the problem with my hyperlink or is there anything else that I should fix?

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
Process.Start("ValidPath")
```

Comment: On which computer does that code run? On which computer does the user want to open the directory?